# Can the universe be considered an isolated system?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, entropy, universe

Is it allowed to consider the physical universe as a thermodynamic isolated system obeying the general second law since the total entropy in a comoving volume does not decrease with time despite cosmic expansion?

Comment: The definition of the verb "isolate" given by Google's dictionary publisher (Oxford Languages) matches "the universe" in the sense given by those terms until 1980:  Since then, however, the concept of cosmic inflation (a period of spatial expansion at rates quasi-exponentially greater than those presently observable by us) has brought out the concept of "local universes" (which, in some contexts, includes "temporal iterations" of a single locality), which may've introduced some confusion:  As far as I can tell, "universe" refers to a "local" version when it's capitalized (as "Universe").

Comment: Yes I am agree with you and I convert your comment like an up voted 

Answer (score 1):

The so called "*Big Freeze*", one of the possible hypothesis put in the field by cosmologists states that the destiny of the Universe will be the thermal death, that is the reaching of the maximum value of entropy and therefore the cancellation of any gradient: in other words the Universe will be perfectly homogeneous and will not host any energetic process anymore.

> **The second principle of thermodynamics tells us that in an isolated system entropy increases irreversibly until it reaches a maximum value and the Universe can be considered by definition an isolated system.**